# Variable Subform Name Requery

Tags: variables, ms-access, vba, subform

I am having an issue when trying to requery a subform using a variable name, I get the error message RunTime Error 2450 "Cannot find the referenced form "Frm_Test".
Please find code below:

```
Private Sub SampleType_AfterUpdate()

varsubform = Me.SampleType.Column(2)
Forms(varsubform).Requery

End Sub
```

The subform Frm_Test is definitely open on the form, is there something I am missing? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `Me("Subformcontrolnamehere").Form.Requery` see http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Comment: Thanks Remou, worked like a charm!